# How to send list of string in webservice through angularjs

Tags: angularjs, web-services, ionic-framework

I'm developing cross platform app in ionic 1 by angularjs where I'm not able to pass list of string in asp.net web service.
angularjs code :

```
var request = {
            params:[]
        };
        request.params.push(jsonObjectA);
        request.params.push({"someString" : "ABCDEF"});
$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: targetUri,
            data: request
        })
```

This is my web Service, which takes List parameter

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string SearchBasedResult(List<string> Id, List<string> type, string storeid)
{
      //some code
}
```

Comment: How does the web service expects the data? Is it in request body or as query parameters?

Comment: web service expects the data from public string SearchBasedResult(List<string> Id, List<string> type, string storeid).  it's query parameters.

Comment: Okay. Then you should use `params` instead of `data` in `$http`. I think `data` sends contents in request body

Answer (score 0):

Do not use Lists as parameter types, instead create a complex object as a single parameter that contains the lists that you require.. example;

```
    public class MyParamterObject
    {
        public List<string> Ids { get; set; }
        public List<string> Types { get; set; }
        public string StoreId { get; set; }
    }
```

Re-write your controller as follows, using new object as parameter:

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string SearchBasedResult(MyParamterObject param)
    {
        //some code
    }
```

Inside of angular create a new object and fill it, naming the properties as described in your MyParameterObject.

**Edit**

Angular call becomes:

```
        var paramObject = {};
        paramObject.Ids = idsList;
        paramObject.Types = typesList;
        paramObject.StoreId = "storeId";


        var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: targetUri,
            data: paramObject
        };

        $http(req);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should send `array string` to your `api` as:

```
var Ids = ["id1", "id2"]
```

This is `List<string> Ids`, or for `types`:

```
var types = ["type1", "type2"]
```

you have to put theme in object and send it to the `API`:

```
var request = {
    Ids: ["id1", "id2"],
    Types = ["type1", "type2"],
    StoreId: "123456"
}

$http({method: 'POST',header:{Content-Type: application/json},url: targetUri,data: request}).then(function(response)
{
    console.log(response)
})
```